# Is there any jax-rs like libraries on Android to implement restful service?

Tags: java, android, rest, jax-rs

Hello guys I have very basic knowledge on rest services. I have implemented a basic program on Java to get output "hello world!" at URI http://localhost:8080/greeting/greet

```
package greeting;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/greet")
public class Greet {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String justGreet(){
        return "hello world!";
    }

}
```

I would like to implement similar kind on Android, so that I can see output at some URI on any browser in that network. I'm confusing which dependencies or libraries have to use for Android to get that. Hoping for answers.

Thanks a ton in Advance!

**Edit:** I have used Retrofit library as suggested, it's executing well but I cannot see the output "Hello World!" at this URI http://192.168.0.104:8080/greeting/greet1, like usig Java and Jax-rs.

here is the implementation

```
package abc.xyz.com.retrotut;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String URL = "http://192.168.0.104:8080/";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ApiService api = retrofit.create(ApiService.class);
    Greeting greet = new Greeting("Hello World!");
    Call<Greeting> call = api.getGreeting(greet);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Greeting>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Greeting> call, Response<Greeting> response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Greeting> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Pojo kind

```
public class Greeting {


private String greet;

public Greeting(String greet) {
    this.greet = greet;
}
}
```

Interface

```
public interface ApiService {

@POST("greeting/greet1")
Call<Greeting> getGreeting(@Body Greeting greet);
}
```

However I'm getting "success", when executing application, I cannot get output what I've wanted. Are there any libraries which should I use or any alternatives?

Comment: Have a look at Retrofit library https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: @SouravGanguly Thanks for the comment. I cannot get the output what I really wanted to get. I've edited my question (did Retrofit implementation as suggested)